# change alt and title of an <i> element by using class name?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I have an `<i>` element with a class and I would like to change its alt and title tags.

My HTML

```
<a class="myspace-hover " target="_blank" href="#">
<i class="mk-jupiter-icon-myspace" alt="myspace" title="myspace"></i>
</a>
```

And this is what I have tried:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("mk-jupiter-icon-myspace")[0] = "test" ;
    document.getElementsByClassName("mk-jupiter-icon-myspace")[1] = "alttest" ;
}
```

As well as:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("mk-jupiter-icon-myspace").title = "test" ;
    document.getElementsByClassName("mk-jupiter-icon-myspace").alt = "alttest" ;
}
```

But evidently I have misunderstood the documentation and what I have been reading.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: A mixture of the first and second was right. You were *so* close!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like HTML collection.

Each member of an HTML collection is an element with its own set of properties.

You need to get the element by index and then set the property you care about:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mk-jupiter-icon-myspace")[0].title = "test" ;
```

---

Note that `alt` is an attribute that provides a text replacement for an **image**. A piece of italic text (which is what `<i>` means) is not an image and cannot have an alt attribute. [Use a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Meanwhile your `title` looks like it would be better suited to the `<a>` element.

Comment: `i` elements, rightly or wrongly, are often used for icons from frameworks such as fontawesome. Which makes the alt and title attributes have some meaning.

Comment: @Jamiec — Rubbish. The ways in which people abuse elements do not magically create support in browsers for attributes which don't belong there.

Comment: @Jamiec — You said it gave the attributes meaning. It doesn't. The browser will ignore the alt attribute. It certainly won't display it if the background image fails to load.